# JQuery Index Element Excluding Element

Tags: jquery, indexing

I'm trying to get the jQuery index of every element excluding the `li` element without the divider. How do I get the index of all elements excluding the divider class?

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>


$('ul li').each(function(i, e) {         
   $(e).index('li:not(.divider)').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this step simply using selector not index like in this example:

```js
$('ul li:not(.divider)').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="divider">divider</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: using `each` is redundant

Comment: each with out divider `ul li:not(.divider)`

Comment: Nothing wrong. I don't understand what would you asking?

Comment: Yes, I understand you can add a class that way, but I need the index (simplified this example for the sake of simplicity) - how would you get that?

Comment: When you only want to add class active to all li without divider, this is simplicity way, but when you want to do something else, give me please more details